# Is it correct to use the to-infinitive after past participles?

Tags: to-infinitive

1. The patches are seen **to** merge or diverge along their lengths.

The -ing shouldn't be used in this sentence?

2. The patch is understood **to** be a useful minimum indicator of the distribution of gas.

Is this **to** ok?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes: both your examples are okay. The "to" is obligatory here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!